# Process has more open sockets than should be allowed by prlimit

Tags: ulimit, resources, lsof

Running debian jessie. The following is done as root to avoid any permissions issues.
First I find the pid of my program, then I check its open file limit to verify that it is set at 1024. But when I count the number of open files, I find 1851.

```
$ pgrep -x process_name
673
$ prlimit --pid 673 --nofile
RESOURCE DESCRIPTION              SOFT HARD UNITS
NOFILE   max number of open files 1024 4096 
$ lsof -n -p 673 | grep -c "IPv4"
1851
```

For good measure, I check that the process doesn't have any subprocesses that it might be delegating file openings to:

```
$ pgrep -P 673
# no output
```

What is going wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Because in the way you are using `lsof`, you are counting everything, not only the file descriptors, use something like this:

```
lsof -n  -p <pid_number> | awk '$5 ~ /([0-9].+)/'
```

But the more easy way is:

```
ls -l /proc/673/fd | wc -l
```

Comment: Ok, I guess this technically answers my question. But then what do I need to limit in order to limit lines that match `$5 ~ /IPv4/`?

Comment: why you need to filter IPV4? we the above command you filter all file descriptor for a process include ipv4 socket file descriptor.

Comment: Maybe you meant some other column besides `$5`? Which column were you trying to filter? Because `$5` for me is "Type" for which IPv4 definitely does not match `/([0-9].+)/`.

Comment: in your question you told, you need to count the file descriptors, any using awk you can filter the output in every column you want, i used column and it's works, this is only for ipv4 network socket lsof -n  | awk 'BEGIN {IGNORECASE=1;} $5 ~ /IPV4/'

Comment: Still has 1700 entries with that command.

Comment: i updated my answer.

Comment: `ls -l /proc/673/fd | wc -l ` returns 1751

Comment: the soft limit is not a hard limit and user can change that number from his shell before run a program.

Comment: I changed the hard limit to 1024 also with `$prlimit --pid 673 --nofile=1024:1024` and it still exhibits the same behavior.

Comment: because you process file descriptors are allocated, if you now restart the process, the process cannot allocate more than 1024 files.

Comment: If I restart the process won't it get a different pid and the changed limits be reset?